# Doubts about event loop , multi-threading, order of executing readFile() in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, readfile

```
fs.readFile("./large.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {
console.log('It is a large file') 

//this file has many words (11X MB). 
//It takes 1-2 seconds to finish reading (usually 1)

});

fs.readFile("./small.txt","utf8", (err, data) => {

for(let i=0; i<99999 ;i++)
console.log('It is a small file');

//This file has just one word. 
//It always takes 0 second
});
```

Result:

The console will always first print "It is a small file" for 99999 times (it takes around 3 seconds to finish printing). 
Then, after they are all printed, the console does not immediately print "It is a large file". (It is always printed after 1 or 2 seconds).

My thought:

So, it seems that the first readFile() and second readFile() functions do not run in parallel. If the two readFile() functions ran in parallel, then I would expect that after "It is a small file" was printed for 99999 times,
the first readFile() is finished reading way earlier (just 1 second) and the console would immediately print out the callback of the first readFile() (i.e. "It is a large file".)

My questions are :

(1a) Does this mean that the first readFile() will start to read file only after the callback of second readFile() has done its work?

(1b) To my understanding, in nodeJs, event loop passes the readFile()  to Libuv multi-thread. However, I wonder in what order they are passed. If these two readFile() functions do not run in parallel, why is the second readFile() function always executed first?

(2) By default, Libuv has four threads for Node.js. So, here, do these two readFile() run in the same thread? Among these four threads, I am not sure whether there is only one for readFile().

Thank you very much for spending your time! Appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (1a) Does this mean that the first readFile() will start to read file only after the callback of second readFile() has done its work?

No.  Each `readFile()` actually consists of multiple steps (open file, read chunk, read chunk ... close file).  The logic flow between steps is controlled by Javascript code in the node.js `fs` library.  But, a portion of each step is implemented by native threaded code in libuv using a thread pool.

So, the first step of the first `readFile()` will be initiated and then control is returned back to the JS interpreter.  Then, the first step of the second `readFile()` will be initiated and then control returned back to the JS interpreter.  It can ping pong back and forth between progress in the two `readFile()` operations as long as the JS interpreter isn't kept busy.  But, if the JS interpreter does get busy for awhile, it will stall further progress when the current step that's proceeding in the background completes.  There's a full step-by-step chronology at the end of the answer if you want to follow the details of each step.

> (1b) To my understanding, in nodeJs, event loop passes the readFile() to Libuv multi-thread. However, I wonder in what order they are passed. If these two readFile() functions do not run in parallel, why is the second readFile() function always executed first?

`fs.readFile()` itself is not implemented in libuv.  It's implemented as a series of individual steps in node.js Javascript.  Each individual step (open file, read chunk, close file) is implemented in libuv, but Javascript in the `fs` library controls the sequencing between steps.  So, think of `fs.readfile()` as a series of calls to libuv.  When you have two `fs.readFile()` operations in flight at the same time, each will have some libuv operation going at any given time and one step for each `fs.readFile()` can be proceeding in parallel due to the thread pool implementation in libuv.  But, between each step in the process, control comes back the JS interpreter.  So, if the interpreter gets busy for some extended portion of time, then further progress in scheduling the next step of the other `fs.readFile()` operation is stalled.

> (2) By default, Libuv has four threads for Node.js. So, here, do these two readFile() run in the same thread? Among these four threads, I am not sure whether there is only one for readFile().

I think this is covered in the previous two explanations.  `readFile()` itself is not implemented in native code of libuv.  Instead, it's written in Javascript with calls to open, read, close operations that are written in native code and use libuv and the thread pool.

Here's a full accounting of what's going on.  To fully understand, one needs to know about these:

**Main Concepts**

1. The single threaded, non-pre-emptive nature of node.js running your Javascript (assuming no `WorkerThreads` are manually coded here - which they aren't).
2. The multi-threaded, native code of the `fs` module's file I/O and how that works.
3. How native code asynchronous operations communicate completion via the event queue and how event loop scheduling works when the JS interpreter is busy doing something.

**Asynchronous, Non-Blocking**

I presume you know that `fs.readFile()` is asynchronous and non-blocking.  That means when you call it, all it does is initiate an operation to read the file and then it goes right onto the next line of code at the top level after the `fs.readFile()` (not the code inside the callback you pass to it).

So, a condensed version of your code is basically this:

```
fs.readFile(x, funcA);
fs.readFile(y, funcB);
```

If we added some logging to this:

```
function funcA() {
    console.log("funcA");
}
function funcB() {
    console.log("funcB");
}

function spin(howLong) {
    let finishTime = Date.now() + howLong;
    // spin until howLong ms passes
    while (Date.now() < finishTime) {}
}

console.log("1");
fs.readFile(x, funcA);
console.log("2");
fs.readFile(y, funcB);
console.log("3");
spin(30000);         // spin for 30 seconds    
console.log("4");
```

You would see either this order:

```
1
2
3
4
A
B
```

or this order:

```
1
2
3
4
B
A
```

Which of the two it was would just depend upon the indeterminate race between the two `fs.readFile()` operations.  Either could happen.   Also, notice that `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` are all logged before any asynchronous completion events can occur.  This is because the single-threaded, non-pre-emptive JS interpreter main thread is busy executing Javascript.  It won't pull the next event out of the event queue until it's done executing this piece of Javascript.

**Libuv Thread Pool**

As you appear to already know, the `fs` module uses a libuv thread pool for running file I/O.  That's independent of the main JS thread so those read operations can proceed independently from further JS execution.  Using native code, file I/O will communicate with the event queue when they are done to schedule their completion callback.

**Indeterminate Race Between Two Asynchronous Operations**

So, you've just created an indeterminate race between the two `fs.readFile()` operations that are likely each running in their own thread.  A small file is much more likely to complete first before the larger file because the larger file has a lot more data to read from the disk.

Whichever `fs.readFile()` finishes first will insert its callback into the event queue first.  When the JS interpreter is free, it will pick the next event out of the event queue.  Whichever one finishes first gets to run its callback first.  Since the small file is likely to finish first (which is what you are reporting), it gets to run its callback.  Now, when it is running its callback, this is just Javascript and even though the large file may finish and insert its callback into the event queue, that callback can't run until the callback from the small file finishes.  So, it finishes and THEN the callback from the large file gets to run.

In general, you should never write code like this unless you don't care at all what order the two asynchronous operations finish in because it's an indeterminate race and you cannot count on which one will finish first.  Because of the asynchronous non-blocking nature of `fs.readFile()`, there is no guarantee that the first file operation initiated will finish first.  It's no different than firing off two separate http requests one after the other.  You don't know which one will complete first.

**Step By Step Chronology**

Here's a step by step chronology of what happens:

1. You call `fs.readFile("./large.txt", ...)`;
2. In Javascript code, that initiates opening the `large.txt` file by calling native code and then returns. The opening of the actual file is handled by libuv in native code and when that is done, an event will be inserted into the JS event queue.
3. Immediately after that operation is initiated, then that first `fs.readFile()` returns (not yet done yet, still processing internally).
4. Now the JS interpreter picks up at the next line of code and runs `fs.readFile("./small.txt", ...);`
5. In Javascript code, that initiates opening the `small.txt` file by calling native code and then returns. The opening of the actual file is handled by libuv in native code and when that is done, an event will be inserted into the JS event queue.
6. Immediately after that operation is initiated, then that second `fs.readFile()` returns (not yet done yet, still processing internally).
7. The JS interpreter is actually free to run any following code or process any incoming events.
8. Then, some time later, one of the two `fs.readFile()` operations finishes its first step (opening the file), an event is inserted into the JS event queue and when the JS interpreter has time, a callback is called.  Since opening each file is about the same operation time, it's likely that the open operation for the `large.txt` file finishes first, but that isn't guaranteed.
9. After the file open succeeds, it initiates an asynchronous operation to read the first chunk from the file.  This again is asynchronous and is handled by libuv so as soon as this is initiated, it returns control back to the JS interpreter.
10. The second file open likely finises next and it does the same thing as the first, initiates reading the first chunk of data from disk and returns control back to the JS interpreter.
11. Then, one of these two chunk reads finishes and inserts an event into the event queue and when the JS interpreter is free, a callback is called to process that.  At this point, this could be either the large or small file, but for purposes of simplicity of explanation, lets assume the first chunk of the large file finishes first.  It will buffer that chunk, see that there is more data to read and will initiate another asynchronous read operation and then return control back to the JS interpreter.
12. Then, the other first chunk read finishes.  It will buffer that chunk and see that there is no more data to read.  At this point, it will issue a file close operation which is again handled by libuv and control is returned back to the JS interpreter.
13. One of the two previous operations completes (a second block read from `large.txt` or a file close of `small.txt`) and its callback is called.  Since the close operation doesn't have to actually touch the disk (it just goes into the OS), let's assume the close operation finishes first for purposes of explanation.   That close triggers the end of the `fs.ReadFile()` for `small.txt` and calls the completion callback for that.
14. So, at this point, `small.txt` is done and `large.txt` has read one chunk from its file and is awaiting completion of the second chunk to read.
15. Your code now executes the `for` loop that takes whatever time that takes.
16. By the point that finishes and the JS interpreter is free again, the 2nd file read from `large.txt` is probably done so the JS interpreter finds it's event in the event queue and executes a callback to do some more processing on reading more chunks from that file.
17. The process of reading a chunk, returning control back to the interpreter, waiting for the next chunk completion event and then buffering that chunk continues until all the data has been read.
18. Then a close operation is initiated for `large.txt`.
19. When that close operation is done, the callback for the `fs.readFile()` for `large.txt` is called and your code that is timing `large.txt` will measure completion.

So, because the logic of `fs.readFile()` is implemented in Javascript with a number of discrete asynchronous steps with each one ultimately handled by libuv (open file, read chunk - N times, close file), there will be an interleaving of the work between the two files.  The reading of the smaller file will finish first just because it has fewer and smaller read operations.  When it finishes, the large file will still have multiple more chunks to read and a close operation left.  Because the multiple steps of `fs.readFile()` are controlled through Javascript, when you do the long `for` loop in the `small.txt` completion, you are stalling the `fs.readFile()` operation for the `large.txt` file too.  Whatever chunk read was in progress when that loop happened will complete in the background, but the next chunk read won't get issued until that small file callback completes.

It appears that there would be an opportunity for node.js to improve the responsiveness of `fs.readFile()` in competitive circumstances like this if that operation was rewritten entirely in native code so that one native code operation could read the contents of the whole file rather than all these transitions back and forth between the single threaded main JS thread and libuv.  If this was the case, the big `for` loop wouldn't stall the progress of `large.txt` because it would be progressing entirely in a libuv thread rather than waiting for some cycles from the JS interpreter in order to get to its next step.

We can theorize that if both files were able to be read in one chunk, then not much would get stalled by the long `for` loop.  Both files would get opened (which should take approximately the same time for each).  Both operations would initiate a read of their first chunk.  The read for the smaller file would likely complete first (less data to read), but actually this depends upon both OS and disk controller logic.  Because the actual reads are handed off to threaded code, both reads will be pending at the same time.  Assuming the smaller read finishes first, it would fire completion and then during the busy loop the large read would finish, inserting an event in the event queue.  When the busy loop finishes, the only thing left to do on the larger file (but still something that can was read in one chunk) would be to close the file which is a faster operation.

But, when the larger file can't be read in one chunk and needs multiple chunks of reading, that's why its progress really gets stalled by the busy loop because a chunk finishes, but the next chunk doesn't get scheduled until the busy loop is done.

**Testing**

So, let's test out all this theory.  I created two files.  `small.txt` is 558 bytes.  `large.txt` is 255,194,500 bytes.

Then, I wrote the following program to time these and allow us to optionally do a 3 second spin loop after the small one finishes.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let doSpin = false;              // -s will set this to true
let fname = "./large.txt";      

for (let i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i++) {
    let arg = process.argv[i];
    console.log(`"${arg}"`);
    if (arg.startsWith("-")) {
        switch(arg) {
            case "-s":
                doSpin = true;
                break;
            default:
                console.log(`Unknown arg ${arg}`);
                process.exit(1);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        fname = arg;
    }
}

function padDecimal(num, n = 3) {
    let str = num.toFixed(n);
    let index = str.indexOf(".");
    if (index === -1) {
        str += ".";
        index = str.length - 1;
    }
    let zeroesToAdd = n - (str.length - index);
    while (zeroesToAdd-- >= 0) {
        str += "0";
    }

    return str;
}

let startTime;
function log(msg) {
    if (!startTime) {
        startTime = Date.now();
    }
    let diff = (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000;    // in seconds
    console.log(padDecimal(diff), ":", msg)
}


function funcA(err, data) {
    if (err) {
       log("error on large");
       log(err);
       return;
    }
    log("large completed");
}

function funcB(err, data) {
    if (err) {
       log("error on small");
       log(err);
       return;
    }
    log("small completed");
    if (doSpin) {
        spin(3000);
        log("spin completed");
    }
}

function spin(howLong) {
    let finishTime = Date.now() + howLong;
    // spin until howLong ms passes
    while (Date.now() < finishTime) {}
}

log("start");
fs.readFile(fname, funcA);
log("large initiated");
fs.readFile("./small.txt", funcB);
log("small initiated");
```

Then (using node v12.13.0), I ran it both with and without the 3 second spin.  Without the spin, I get this output:

```
0.000 : start
0.015 : large initiated
0.016 : small initiated
0.021 : small completed
0.240 : large completed
```

This shows a 0.219 second delta between the time to complete small and large (while running both at the same time).

Then, inserting the 3 second delay, we get this output:

```
0.000 : start
0.003 : large initiated
0.004 : small initiated
0.009 : small completed
3.010 : spin completed
3.229 : large completed
```

We have the exact same 0.219 second delta between the time to complete the small and the large (while running both at the same time).  This shows that the large `fs.readFile()` essentially made no progress during the 3 second spin.  It's progress was completely blocked.  As we've theorized in the previous explanation, this is apparently because the progression from one chunked read to the next is written in Javascript and while the spin loop is running, that progression to the next chunk is blocked so it can't make any further progress.

**How Big A File Makes Big File Finish Second?**

If you look in the code for `fs.readFile()` in the source for node v12.13.0, you can find that the chunk size it reads is 512 * 1024 which is 512k.  So, in theory, it's possible that the larger file might finish first if it can be read in one chunk.  Whether that actually happens or not depends upon some OS and disk implementation details, but I thought I'd try it on my laptop running a current version of Windows 10 with an SSD drive.

I found that, for a 255k "large" file, it does finish before the small file (essentially in execution order).  So, because the large file read is started before the small file read, even though it has more data to read, it will still finish before the small file.

```
0.000 : start
0.003 : large initiated
0.003 : small initiated
0.007 : large completed
0.008 : small completed
```

Keep in mind, this is OS and disk dependent so this is not guaranteed.

Comment: I heard that it is the event loop which passes the IO operation to multi-thread. I also heard that top-level code is executed before event loop stage. Also, you said readFile is top-level code. Then, based on these three statements, I am confused when I/O operation actually starts.

Comment: @JackyChau - I/O operation starts immediately when you call `fs.readFile()`. The I/O is handed off to a native code thread in the thread pool.  As soon as that happens `fs.readFile()` returns and the next statement at the same level of code as it, will get to run.  It is not the event loop that initiates things. The event queue is for communicating completion.  Initiating things is just a function call into native code (Javascript can call native code directly through  the node.js add-on interface). The native code then engages the threadpool on the file I/O and immediately returns back to JS.

Comment: @JackyChau - Please don't be confused by the phrase "top level code".  I wanted to say the "next line of code", but because you're using inline callbacks, I didn't want you to think the next line to execute was in the callback so I tried to find a different phrase.  It's the next line of code at the same level as `fs.readFile()` that executes next.

Comment: ```
Line 1: fs.readFile("./large.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {
Line2: console.log('Large file took 2 second to finish reading ')})
Line 3: for(let i=0; i<99999 ; i++){console.log('blocking 4 secs')
Link 4: fs.readFile("./small.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => { console.log('small file took 0 second finish reading)
```
Suppose line 1 is executed at 00:00:05, then theoretically the IO operation is finished at 00:00:07 and is put into the event queue. Line 3 is finished executing at ~00:00:09 ; at 00:00:09 another I/O opera in line 4 is executed.

Comment: (Continue) The callback of readFile in line 4 seems to be queued after the callback of readFile in line 1; So, why in the end still the callback of readFile in line 4 runs first?

Comment: @JackyChau -  A callback is only queued when the asynchronous operation running in the native code threads finishes.  When that happens has nothing to do with when the asynchronous operation was started.  Please read my step by step chronology.  I think it's all explained there.

Comment: @JackyChau - I've expanded the step-by-step chronology to cover how `fs.readFile()` is actually written which is a series of transitions back and forth between Javascript and native code in libuv.  This shows how the reading of `large.txt` gets stalled for a bit during the long `for` loop in the `small.txt` completion callback.

Comment: @JackyChau - I added specific point by point answers to the questions you posed in your original question.

Comment: @JackyChau - I added a test program and test data to the answer.

Comment: Wow, It is very detailed. Thank you very much for your effort !  Sorry for my late reply.

Comment: @JackyChau - Are you aware that you can select a "best answer" here by clicking the checkmark next to an answer.  That will indicate to the community which answer you thought helped you the most.  It will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. Sorry, I am new to Stackoverflow. Just now, I have selected a "best answer"

Comment: @JackyChau - No problem.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't possibly believe that node would delay the large file read until the callback for the small file read had completed, and so I did a little more instrumentation of your example:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const readLarge = process.argv.includes('large');
const readSmall = process.argv.includes('small');

if (readLarge) {
    console.time('large');
    fs.readFile('./large.txt', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        console.timeEnd('large');
        if (readSmall) {
            console.timeEnd('large (since busy wait)');
        }
    });
}

if (readSmall) {
    console.time('small');
    fs.readFile('./small.txt', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        console.timeEnd('small');
        var stop = new Date().getTime();
        while(new Date().getTime() < stop + 3000) { ; } // busy wait
        console.time('large (since busy wait)');
    });
}
```

(Note that I replaced your loop of console.logs with a 3s busy wait).

Running this against node v8.15.0 I get the following results:

```
$ node t small # read small file only
small: 0.839ms
$ node t large # read large file only
large: 447.348ms
$ node t small large # read both files
small: 3.916ms
large: 3252.752ms
large (since busy wait): 247.632ms
```

These results seem sane; the large file took ~0.5s to read on its own, but when the busy waiting callback interfered for 2s, it completed relatively soon (~1/4s) thereafter. Tweaking the length of the busy wait keeps this relatively consistent, so I'd be willing to just say this was some kind of scheduling overhead and not necessarily a sign that the large file I/O had not been running during the busy wait.

But then I ran the same program against node 10.16.3, and here's what I got:

```
$ node t small
small: 1.614ms
$ node t large
large: 1019.047ms
$ node t small large
small: 3.595ms
large: 4014.904ms
large (since busy wait): 1009.469ms
```

Yikes! Not only did the large file read time more than double (to ~1s), it certainly appears as if no I/O *at all* had been completed before the busy wait concluded! i.e., it sure looks like the busy wait in the main thread prevented any I/O at all from happening on the large file.

I suspect that this change from 8.x to 10.x is a result of this "optimization" in Node 10: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/17054. This change, which splits the read of large files into multiple operations, seems to be appropriate for smoothing performance of the system in general purpose cases, but it is likely exacerbated by the unnatural long main thread processing / busy wait in this scenario. Presumably, without the main thread yielding, the I/O is not getting a chance to advance to the next range of bytes in the large file to be read.

It would seem that, with Node 10.x, it is important to have a responsive main thread (i.e., one that yields frequently, and doesn't busy wait like in this example) in order to sustain I/O performance of large file reads.

Comment: This would actually explain some of the questions I've seen of the form why is node.js slower than (insert language X) and I couldn't replicate the results on my machine

Comment: Just came across this lively discussion related to the large file behavior change in Node 10.x: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/25741

Comment: Wow. Very nice job! So, it seems that my understanding is correct, and just that there is an awkward and exceptional issue. I am actually a beginner in Node.js. I felt glad that my inquiry and doubt have motivated you guys to discover something new.

Comment: If you look at the end of my answer here, I looked at how the actual code for `fs.readFile()` works and worked through the actual steps for these two competing operations.   Because `fs.readFile()` is a multi-step operation and the steps are controlled from Javascript, when the busy loop happens, it stalls any further progress on reading more chunks from `large.txt`.  If `fs.readFile()` was written entirely in threaded native code, then it could proceed, even though the JS interpreter was busy, but this is not the case.

Comment: So, during the busy loop, the next read chunk for `large.txt` can complete in the background, but then further progress gets stalled because the JS interpreter is busy.

Answer (score 1):

File I/O in Node.js runs in separate thread. But this does not matter. Node.js **always** executes all callbacks in the main thread. I/O callbacks are never executed in a separate thread (the file read operation is done in a separate thread then when it is finished will signal the main thread to run your callback). This *essentially* makes node.js single-threaded because all the code you write runs in the main thread (we're of course ignoring the worker_threads module/API which allows you to manually execute code in separate threads).

But the bytes in the files **are** read in parallel (or as parallel as your hardware allows - depending on the number of free DMA channels, which disk each file is from etc). What is parallel is the **wait**. Asynchronous I/O in any language (node.js, Java, C++, Python etc.) is basically an API that allows you to **wait** in parallel but handle events in a single thread. There is a word for this kind of *parallel*: concurrent. It is essentially parallel wait (while data is handled in parallel by your hardware) but not parallel code execution.

Comment: Sincerely thank you for your detailed reply. Sorry, I am not sure whether I really understand it. Do you mean the two I/O operations in my two readFile() functions in my code do not execute at the same time?

Comment: This is wrong.  File I/O in node.js uses a thread pool which has multiple threads.

Comment: I tried to figure out the following steps. I am not sure. Step 1: The second readFile() starts its I/O operation  Step 2: When it's done, send the callback to the main thread to process. Step3: The first readFile() starts its I/O operation Step 4: When it's done, send the callback to the main thread.

Comment: @JackyChau It's more like step 1: first readFile() is scheduled, step2: second readFile() is scheduled, step3: end of script, nothing else to execute so node.js enters event loop processing, step3.1: both first and second readFile() operations are started and the event loop waits for either to complete, step4: the first file to complete reading triggers its callback - note that this can be either readFile() but since the second file is smaller it obviously completes first, step5: the next readFile() to complete triggers its callback

Comment: @jfriend00 - Editing that part

Comment: @JackyChau What one needs to keep in mind is that node.js cannot process callback handling (event loop processing) until there's no more javascript to execute - this is why infinite loops blocks I/O and timers

Comment: @slebetman I think your steps are more reasonable. I also thought of these steps. But, I am not able to convenience myself. The callback of the readFile function (smaller file) takes around 4 seconds to finish (because of the 99999 times looping). So, within that four seconds of printing, the I/O operation for another readFile function (for bigger file) should have already been finished way earilier and put to the event queue. Then, after the messages (99999times) have been printed, the callback of another function should have been called immediately. But why it needs to wait for one second?

Comment: @JackyChau - see the answer by Myk Willis - this seems to be an unintended consequence of optimisation which breaks my theoretical explanation of javascript I/O processing. And note that this behaves differently with different versions of node so it's not a general node.js mechanism but depends on specific implementation

Comment: Wow. Very nice job! So, it seems that my understanding is correct, and just that there is an awkward and exceptional issue. I am actually a beginner in Node.js. I felt glad that my inquiry and doubt have motivated you guys discover something new.

Comment: @JackyChau stackoverflow is awesome. I've seen Chris Espinosa (one of the original Apple employees from when Jobs & Woz were operating out of a garage) answer questions on Xcode and Guido van Rossum (creator of Python) answer questions on Python

Answer (score 1):

I think that you understand the behavior of event loop and libuv, don't lose your way.

My answers :

1a) Of course the two read file are executed in two different threads , I tried to run your code replacing a large file with a small one and the output was 
`It is a large file
 It is a small file`

1b) The second call just end before in your case and then the callback is invoked before.

2 ) As you said , libuv has four threads by default , but be sure that the default are not changed setting the env variable UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE ( http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html )

I tried to work with a large and a big file , to read the big file my PC take 23/25 ms , to read the small file it take 8/10 ms. 
When I try to read both the process terminate in 26/27 ms and this demonstrate that the two read file are executed in parallel .

Try to measure the time that your code take from small file callback to large file callback :

```js
console.log(process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE)
const fs = require('fs')
const start = Date.now()
let smallFileEnd


fs.readFile("./alphabet.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {
    console.log('It is a large file') 
    console.log(`From the start to now are passed ${Date.now() - start} ms`)
    console.log(`From the small file end to now are passed ${Date.now() - smallFileEnd} ms`)
    //this file has many words (11X MB). 
    //It takes 1-2 seconds to finish reading (usually 1)
    // 18ms to execute
}); 
 

fs.readFile("./stackoverflow.js","utf8", (err, data) => {
    
    for(let i=0; i<99999 ;i++)
        if(i === 99998){
            smallFileEnd = Date.now()
            console.log('is a small file ')
            console.log(`From the start to now are passed ${Date.now() - start} ms`)
             // 4/7 ms to execute
        }
            
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to digest your answer. In the meanwhile, would you mind also spend some time reading Myk Willis's reply and see whether you will have some different thoughts afterwards?

Comment: Hi @JackyChau ,
I had a look to Mik ' s reply , is a good point and the first part of the reply is similar to my comment , the second part speak about a pull request about an  optimization to the readFile method , and this from my point of view is not related to this . Your understanding of this topic is fine , just try to do as I and Milk did , log how much time pass between the small callback and the large callback and let us know :)